# how to count all distinct records in many-to-many relations in django ORM?

Tags: python, django, orm

class Project(models.Model):
     categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

```
class Category(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField()
```

now, i make some queryset:

```
query = Project.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3,4])
```

and i like to get list of all distinct categories in this queryset with count of projects with refering to these categories - exactly i would like to get that results:

```
category1 - 10 projects
category2 - 5 projects
```

that is opposite to this query:

```
query2 = query.annotate(Count('categories'))
```

what return me:

```
project1 - 2categories
project2 - 7categories
```

how can i make it in django ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Category.objects.filter(project__in=query).annotate(Count('project'))
```

Comment: yes, but i like to get only categories from this specific queryset (Project.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3,4])
), not from all categories in database